# Access data through an API with Python

Tags: python, json, api, post, request

I am a complete beginner  in the use of API in python. I would like to access this data about Covid 19 vaccination : https://datavaccin-covid.ameli.fr/explore/dataset/donnees-de-vaccination-par-commune/api/

I tried some stuff and it's never working can someone please help me.

This the code I wrote :

```
import requests

import json

import pandas as pd

query = """{
"nhits":183120,
"dataset":"donnees-de-vaccination-par-commune",
"rows":10,
"start":0,
"facet":[
"semaine_injection",
"commune_residence",
"libelle_commune",
"classe_age",
"libelle_classe_age"
 ],
 "format":"json",
 "timezone":"UTC"

 }""" 


url = 'https://datavaccin-    covid.ameli.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=donnees-de-vaccination-par-commune&q=&facet=semaine_injection&facet=commune_residence&facet=libelle_commune&facet=classe_age&facet=libelle_classe_age&refine.commune_residence=13001'


r = requests.post(url, json= query)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

and I get an error 400

The url I used is the link at the end of the website, I am not sure it is the good one to use :
[url used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfgin.png)

Thank you

Comment: Post code as text, not as image.

Comment: Post the **full code** in the question.

Comment: sorry its the first time I use stack overflow. I modified the question. Thanks @Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @James for your help. This works

```
url = 'https://datavaccin-   covid.ameli.fr/api/records/1.0/search/'

query = {"dataset":"donnees-de-vaccination-par-commune",
"rows":100,
"start":0,
"facet":[
"semaine_injection",
"commune_residence",
"libelle_commune",
"classe_age",
"libelle_classe_age"
],
"format":"json",
"timezone":"UTC"}

r = requests.get(url, params= query)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

I had to use params, change the url and get rid of the triple quotes to make it work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the "POST" method when you need the "GET" method. The POST method lets you send information to their server. The GET method retrieves only.

```python
r = requests.get(url, json=query)
```

Also, your query doesn't need all the """ outside the curly braces.

Comment: Thanks @James I tried the "GET" method but it gives me this error :                 403
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Is there a key I should use @James ?

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct authentication if you are getting the 403, you might need it for specific datasets.  I've had a quick look and they seem to have good documentation so I'd recommend you read through it step-by-step for the data you need - https://help.opendatasoft.com/apis/ods-search-v1/#search-api-v1

Also, using their console docs will help you narrow down the filters to use - https://datavaccin-covid.ameli.fr/api/v2/console

You probably need to setup an API key if you havn't already

Comment: Sorry @James I read the documentation and I really do not understand what I have to do. How can I set up an api key please

Comment: If you go here - https://datavaccin-covid.ameli.fr/api/v2/console  on the right side you should see a green box that says "Authorize". Click the box and it will pop up asking you to input a value. This can be anything you want and will act as your API key. You then add this to your query as a value with the key of "apikey"

Comment: thanks a lot @James I generated an API key and I added to the query and I still get access forbidden what do you mean when you say "add it to the query" Also am I using the right url please ?

Comment: I've had a play around and I'm getting the same error. Looking at the documentation I think you need a specific "Opendatasoft" account and generate an API key via that.  So it appears the data is not free for anyone to access without the above account in place. Here is the authentication info i could find- https://help.opendatasoft.com/apis/ods-explore-v2/#section/Authentication